# why am I not getting the second validation?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I am trying to validate my signup form, but I am getting the desired output from the first, and third, but I try to validate if it's short or too common. I got nothing, but I can have matched validation

```
    $('#signup-form').submit(function() {
        email = document.getElementById("exampleInputEmail").value;
        fname = document.getElementById("exampleInputFname").value;
        lname = document.getElementById("exampleInputLname").value;
        password1 = document.getElementById("exampleInputPassword1").value;
        password2 = document.getElementById("exampleInputPassword2").value;
        if(fname == "" || lname == "" || email == "" || password1 == "" || password2 == ""){
            $("#errorname").html("Please fill out the form");
        }else{
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:'xxxxx',
                data:{
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': CSRF_TOKEN,
                    'first_name':fname,
                    'last_name':lname,
                    'email':email,
                    'password1':password1,
                    'password2':password2,
                },
                success : function(data){
                    console.log(data)
                    if(data['message']['email'] == 'Enter a valid email address.' || data['message']['email'] == 'User with this Email address already exists.'){
                        $("#erroremail").html(data['message']['email'][0]);
                    }
                    if(data['message']['password2'] == 'This password is too short.'){
                         $("#errorpass").html(data['message']['password2'][0]);
                    }
                    if(data['message']['password2'] == "The two password fields didn't match."){
                        $("#errorpass").html(data['message']['password2'][0]);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

JSON response

```
message:
email: ["User with this Email address already exists."]
password2: Array(3)
0: "This password is too short. It must contain at least 8 characters."
1: "This password is too common."
2: "This password is entirely numeric."
```

Comment: Can you upload a snippet with your setup so we can see the whole thing?

Comment: `password2` is an array of 3 strings, yet you're comparing the array itself to a string. It looks like you need to loop through and check all strings within the array.

Comment: @estavillo I update the snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently password2 is an array, as Rory McCrossan mentioned. You cannot compare an array with a string, but you can check if the string is within the array with indexOf, indexOf will return the index where the data is found in the array and -1 if it isn't there (hence the > -1). Try this

```
if(data['message']['password2'].indexOf('This password is too short.') > -1){
     $("#errorpass").html(data['message']['password2'][0]);
}
if(data['message']['password2'].indexOf("The two password fields didn't match.") > -1){
    $("#errorpass").html(data['message']['password2'][0]);
}
```